# Linkedin request using proxy

Tags: python, python-requests

Linkedin is blocked in my country, so I'm trying to use proxy to log in.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
p = {'http': 'http://54.167.184.222:3128', 'https': 'https://54.167.184.222:3128'}

client = requests.Session()
client.proxies.update(p)

HOMEPAGE_URL = 'https://linkedin.com/'
LOGIN_URL = 'https://www.linkedin.com/uas/login-submit'

html = client.get(HOMEPAGE_URL).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
csrf = soup.find(id="loginCsrfParam-login")['value']

login_information = {
    'session_key':'Login',
    'session_password':'Password',
    'loginCsrfParam': csrf,
}

client.post(LOGIN_URL, data=login_information)
```

But I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/afanasev/linkedin/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 324, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/home/afanasev/linkedin/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 506, in urlopen
    raise SSLError(e)
requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.SSLError: hostname '54.167.184.222' doesn't match either of 'www.linkedin.com', 'linkedin.com'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/afanasev/PycharmProjects/linkedin/test.py", line 12, in <module>
    html = client.get(HOMEPAGE_URL).content
  File "/home/afanasev/linkedin/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 394, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/home/afanasev/linkedin/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 382, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/home/afanasev/linkedin/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 485, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/home/afanasev/linkedin/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 379, in send
    raise SSLError(e)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: hostname '54.167.184.222' doesn't match either of 'www.linkedin.com', 'linkedin.com'
```

I've never used proxy in python earlier and I don't understand what's wrong here. I've checked proxy in firefox - it's valid.

Comment: Which country are you in...?

Comment: Well, if linkedin is not accessible to you, then you can access through proxies that's right. But the proxies need to be whitelisted as LinkedIn have a strong detection and banning for the spam proxies.

Comment: requests will automatically check if the certificate is valid to a certain degree. To disable such validation, try to do: `client.get(HOMEPAGE_URL, verify=False)`

Comment: @JafferWilson Russia, it's sad, but LinkedIn is blocked for us by government...

Comment: @HamZa, it seems to work now, thanks, I'll try to go deeper